# Transform an object to its subclass in Java

Tags: java, oop, class-hierarchy

This is not a regular question, please listen to my explain.

I have an object of class `Animal`. How can I transform it to its subclass `Cat`? Like this:

```
Animal a = new Animal();
Cat c = (Cat) a;
```

Of course, I know It's not possible casting directly from `Animal` to `Cat`. But I don't want to manually create a new `Cat` and copy the fields from `Animal` to it. Because sometimes I have lots of class hierarchies which need to transform. How can I solve it by a general way?

Comment: Why are they Animal instances in the first place? If you could create them as Cats in the first place, that would solve your problem.

Comment: Start with `Animal c = new Cat();`?

Comment: @guitarsteve Unfortunately, I was indeed considering an unusual question. It's not like what you say.

Comment: @cricket_007 Unfortunately, I was indeed considering an unusual question. It's not like what you say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring the fact, that in your example you want to inverse the as-is relation (as in "an apple is-a fruit" vs "a fruit is-an apple") - which is pointless to a certain degree.

But lets imagine a case, where you have to make a potate *look like* an apple. So what you'll do is to carve out all the pulp and put the potato into the apple (I use the fruit example here because with animals it gets a bit messy).
This is either called proxying or wrapping.

Both techniques can be done in java either statically or dynamically.

statically: a Wrapper:

- Create new Class, i.e. VeggiAppleWrapper
- let it extend Apple (so anything it wraps looks like an apple)
- define a constructor that accepts the other type (i.e. Potato)
- implement/override the methods that are common and delegate the calls to the wrapped object
- implement all other methods throwing an UnsupportedOperationException

dynamically: a Proxy:

- you have to define an interface at least for the target type (i.e. `interface Apple`)
- create a proxy instance using [Proxy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html)
- use the `Apple` interface in the list of implemented interface
- implement a `MethodInvocationHandler` that does the forwarding for you, similar to the Wrapper, but using [Reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html)
- cast the proxy to `Apple`

Alternatives to using Java's dynamic proxy are code generation libraries such as [CGLib](https://github.com/cglib/cglib) or [Javaassist](http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/) that generate a subclass of your target type at runtime, which is basically the same as the wrapper but implemented like the proxy.

In order to just copy the values from animal to the cat instance (as animal is a superclass, some fields should be common), you could use the reflection api as well

```
for(Field f : Animal.class.getDeclaredFields()) { 
  f.setAccessible(true)
  f.set(cat, f.get(animal));
}
```

This is just a simple example, without exception handling and without considering the fields of Animal's superclass (`getDeclaredFields` only retrieves the field of *this* class).

Comment: I'm afraid you misunderstand my opinion. Your solution is really good for delegating a class to another. But my question is more specific. Animal is Cat's superclass. I don't need to adapt any method of Cat, what I want is copying the common fields from Animal to Cat, while other unique fields of Cat remains default.

Comment: This works! It's just what I want. Reflection is a great technology haha. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

What about creating a copy-constructor in the subclass?

```
public Cat(Animal animal) { super(animal); }
```

Declare such constructor in `Animal` class and just pass a control to it from any subclass by using `super(animal)`, where you will define your custom logic.

Comment: It's a good idea and easy to implement. But infact I don't have any write permissions to these classes. Imagine I was called to add a function to the obvious sources which doesn't belongs to me.

Comment: So you want to do illegal downcasts on objects which classes you don't control. Sounds like a good plan /s. You are stuck with calling getters and setters then, enjoy.

Answer (score -1):

I think you do it right

```
Animal animal = new Animal();
Cat cat = new Cat();

public void foo(){
  animal = cat; //works because Animal is parent class
  cat = (Cat) animal; //you cast Animal to Cat like as parent to child
}
```

Check this out https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

I hope it will helps

Comment: This does not answer what is being asked, of course you can cast a `Cat` object to fit a `Cat` variable, the OP wants to place a `Animal` object in a `Cat` variable.

Comment: Sorry, my "a" is really an object of Animal, not an Animal reference of Cat object.

Comment: @jinge Is any of answer solving your problem? If not please provide more details of your problem.

Comment: Thanks. One of the answers is really helpful, I am verifying whether it solve my problem. I will accept it or provide more details.